# MultipleBagFetchException using a JoinTable with OneToMany?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a unidirectional one-to-many relationship, but there is a join table in between the two tables. For example:

Parent table (CUSTOMER):

```
+----+------+-----+
| ID | NAME | ... |
+----+------+-----+
```

Join table (CUSTOMER_TO_PHONE):

```
+---------+----------+
| CUST_ID | PHONE_ID |
+---------+----------+
```

Child table (PHONE):

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| ID | AREA_CODE | NUMBER |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

Obviously, from a SQL perspective, you'd do something like:

```
select C.NAME, P.AREA_CODE, P.NUMBER
from CUSTOMER C, CUSTOMER_TO_PHONE CTP, PHONE P
where C.ID = CTP.CUST_ID and CTP.PHONE_ID = P.ID;
```

From a JPA perspective, I'm trying to make it so I don't have to make an entity class for the join table, hence my attempt at using `@JoinTable`. Here is my attempt:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @JoinTable(
        name = "CUSTOMER_TO_PHONE",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CUST_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Phone> phoneNumbers;
}

@Entity @Table(name = "PHONE")
public class Phone {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "AREA_CODE")
    private int areaCode;

    private int number;
}
```

However, this is giving me a lovely exception when I attempt to load the `EntityManager`:
`org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not seeing it. Since it's unidirectional, I wouldn't think Phone needs some sort of reference back to Customer.

Comment: I'm using `EntityManager.find(Customer.class, 1);` to attempt to get a customer. No custom HQL. The exception happens when creating the `EntityManager`.

Comment: Do these entities have other collection property?

Comment: Actually, I take that back. In my real code, there's a series of two join tables... So, table -> join table -> child -> join table -> grandchild. I removed the second JoinTable in the first child and it was able to do it. How can I get it to do the same for the grandchild? Does it have to be a lazy fetch?

Comment: Yes, you cannot simultaneously fetch more than one bag. So others should be lazy. But again, it looks like you have a @ManyToMany relationship, I would change the annotations.

Comment: It's not really customers/phones, I was just using that to illustrate the example. It's definitely @OneToMany in my real use case. I'll try it with lazy fetching. Thanks!

Comment: Either you join fetch to only one bag, or you use Sets instead of Lists.